# How to separate one list in two via list comprehension or otherwise

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If have a list of dictionary items like so:

```
L = [{"a":1, "b":0}, {"a":3, "b":1}...]
```

I would like to split these entries based upon the value of "b", either 0 or 1.

```
A(b=0) = [{"a":1, "b":1}, ....]
B(b=1) = [{"a":3, "b":2}, .....]
```

I am comfortable with using simple list comprehensions, and i am currently looping through the list L two times.

```
A = [d for d in L if d["b"] == 0]
B = [d for d in L if d["b"] != 0]
```

Clearly this is not the most efficient way.

An else clause does not seem to be available within the list comprehension functionality.

Can I do what I want via list comprehension?

Is there a better way to do this?

I am looking for a good balance between readability and efficiency, leaning towards readability.

Thanks!

update:
thanks everyone for the comments and ideas! the most easiest one for me to read is the one by Thomas. but i will look at Alex' suggestion as well. i had not found any reference to the collections module before.

Comment: I assume that the second code sample has a typo for the values for key "b"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a list comprehension. List comprehensions are for when you want a single list result. You obviously don't :) Use a regular for loop:

```
A = []
B = []
for item in L:
    if item['b'] == 0:
        target = A
    else:
        target = B
    target.append(item)
```

You can shorten the snippet by doing, say, `(A, B)[item['b'] != 0].append(item)`, but why bother?

Comment: you don't need to compare `item['b']` with `0` in this particular case.

Comment: That depends on what the possible values of item['b'] are, but yes, typically you would use 'if item['b']:' instead, and swap the if and else suites.

Answer (score 3):

If the `b` value can be only 0 or 1, @Thomas's simple solution is probably best. For a more general case (in which you want to discriminate among several possible values of `b` -- your sample "expected results" appear to be completely divorced from and contradictory to your question's text, so it's far from obvious whether you actually need some generality;-):

```
from collections import defaultdict

separated = defaultdict(list)
for x in L:
  separated[x['b']].append(x)
```

When this code executes, `separated` ends up with a `dict` (actually an instance of `collections.defaultdict`, a `dict` subclass) whose keys are all values for `b` that actually occur in `dict`s in list `L`, the corresponding values being the separated sublists.  So, for example, if `b` takes only the values `0` and `1`, `separated[0]` would be what (in your question's text as opposed to the example) you want as list `A`, and `separated[1]` what you want as list `B`.